# How to get both key and value from list separately with linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, key-value

[image: Screenshot for debugging]I started off using a randomized array for a quiz that I am doing, but after I got that working I realized that there was no way for me to be able to keep track of the answer that the user selected. I had been shown how to use some shuffle algorithm but it just confused me.

So I decided to create a `List<KeyValuePair>` to hold the answers from my dataset, the key is a string that is for the dataset row and the value is an integer, that is 1 for the correct answer then 0 for the wrong answer.

So what I am doing is, I have four buttons being stylized with css, I'm turning the button text into one of the four answers. This may sound like bad programming practice but its the only thing I can come up with and that is to change the tab order attribute to either a 1 or a 0 so I can keep track of the answer to display in a results page at the end.

The code I am using is this...

```
ds = MyDs(1);

System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

var QA = new List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>();

QA.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CorrectAnswer"].ToString(),1));
QA.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WrongAnswer1"].ToString(), 0));
QA.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WrongAnswer2"].ToString(), 0));
QA.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WrongAnswer3"].ToString(), 0));

var myQa = QA.OrderBy(c=> rnd.Next()).Select(c=>c.Key.ToString()).ToList();

Label5.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Question"].ToString();

Button1.Text = myQa[0].ToString();
Button2.Text = myQa[1].ToString();
Button3.Text = myQa[2].ToString();
Button4.Text = myQa[3].ToString();
```

this is fine when you look at myQa, the key shows up like it should but if I do this...

```
var myQa = QA.OrderBy(c=> rnd.Next()).Select(c=>c.Key.ToString() + c.Value.ToString()).ToList();
```

then my buttons text adds the key and value to the text, and I don't want that, I just want the key to show up in the button text, and then be able to access its value.

Any ideas or where I am missing something? I'm assuming that its in my query and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you could use ToDictionary method instead of ToList. It accepts key selector and value selector parameters. And the you can

```
   var myQa = QA.OrderBy(c=> rnd.Next()).ToDictionary(ks=>ks.Key.ToString(), vs=>vs..Value.ToString());
   foreach(var keyValuePair in myQa)
   {
       Button button = new Button();
       button.Text = keyValuePair.Key;
       button.Tag= keyValuePair.Value;
       SomeParentControl.Controls.Add(button);
   }
```

In this way you'll have both the key and the value in one enumeration.

Also you can do like this:

```
   var myQaButtons = QA.OrderBy(c=> rnd.Next()).Select(c=>new Button{Text = c.Key, Tag = c.Value}).ToList();
   myQaButtons.ForEach(b=>SomeParentControl.Controls.Add(b));
```

Or simply

```
   var myQa = QA.OrderBy(c=> rnd.Next()).Select(c=>new {c.Key, c.Value}).ToList();

   Button1.Text = myQa[0].Key;
   Button1.Tag = myQa[0].Value
   Button2.Text = myQa[1].Key;
   Button2.Tag = myQa[1].Value;
   Button3.Text = myQa[2].Key;
   Button3.Tag = myQa[2].Value;
   Button4.Text = myQa[3].Key;
   Button4.Tag = myQa[3].Value;
```

Comment: This I understand, well I understand the part after simply. I just tried as you suggested but there is no myQa[0].Key or myQa.Value

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me on this, I wasn't sure that you would and I appreciate that you did :) I just checked over the code, I used labels instead of the buttons Tag, asp buttons, to the best of my knowledge, don't have that attribute,(Is the Button Tag property something in WinForms). But it all worked perfectly, Thanks again, it was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you need a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Here:

`var myQa = QA.OrderBy(c=> rnd.Next()).Select(c=>c.Key.ToString() + c.Value.ToString()).ToList();`

you are selecting both `key` and its `value`. Instead you can just do:

`var myQa = QA.OrderBy(c=> rnd.Next()).Select(c=>c.Key.ToString()).ToList();` to get the key

`var kValue = QA.Where(m=> m.Key == "Correct Answer").FirstOrDefault().Value;` <- willl get you a value for a particular key.

Comment: I changed it over to a dictionary list, but still don't see how to get the value. This is my first time using this type of collection, so forgive me if I don't entirely understand

Comment: I looked at your edit, would I have to the same query for WrongAnswer1, WrongAnswer2 and WrongAnswer3? If so then how do I know for sure that the right value is to the right key? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I tried what your edit suggested and as I stepped through the code I noticed that the value was 0 for the CorrectAnswer and it should be 1.

Comment: When you try to edit your question, you can see various buttons on the Tab strip. One of them says `Image <img>` use it.

Comment: ok, I just added it. I added watches so you could see after I stepped through it.

Comment: @user2970223 what's the value of : `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CorrectAnswer"].ToString()`

Comment: The value for just this one record is 2.

Comment: @user2970223 and the key?

Comment: For this record it would be as follows.. CorrectAnswer key = 2 value = 1, WrongAnswer1 key = 3 value = 0, WrongAnswer2 key = 5 value = 0, WrongAnswer3 key = 4 value = 0. All correctanswers have a value of 1 and all wronganswers have a value of 0.